# Difficulty Scraping Website Content Using BeautifulSoup and Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I'm facing a challenge while trying to scrape content from the following URL: https://www.realestate.com.au/find-agent/moorabbin-vic-3189?pid=rea:hp:search-box-search:find-agent&page=1&source=results

The issue is that when I manually open the URL, I can see the content, but when I try to retrieve it programmatically using BeautifulSoup or Selenium, it doesn't respond as expected. Here's an example of the code I'm using:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service as ChromeService
from math import ceil
import bs4
from PIL import Image
import datetime
import requests

import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

url = 'https://www.realestate.com.au/find-agent/moorabbin-vic-3189?pid=rea:hp:search-box-search:find-agent&page=1&source=results'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()

driver.get(url)

# Wait for the elements to become present
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 50)
elements = wait.until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located((By.CLASS_NAME, 'agent-card__details')))
print(elements)
```